# Security vulnerabilities with quoting in SQL

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-db

i am doing a simple select using the zend\db\sql classes and i got the following error.

> Notice: Attempting to quote a value in Zend\Db\Adapter\Platform\Mysql
>   without extension/driver support can introduce security
>   vulnerabilities in a production environment. in
>   C:\wamp\vendor\zendframework\zend-db\Zend\Db\Adapter\Platform\Mysql.php
>   on line 134

Below is my code that output the errors.

```
$select2 = $this->sql->select()
->from('users')
->where(array("fbid = ?" => $id));
$selectSqlString = $this->sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($select2);
$this->dbo->query($selectSqlString, Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
```

May i know why does this happens and what should i do to prevent it?

Cheers~

Comment: Hi Slay, do you know how do get rid of that warning now ?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the code for the [MySQL class](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Platform/Mysql.php#L111)  (I know that the provided link is for ZF2, but it looks like the same code is used), it would seem, that you are missing both the PDO and mysqli extension. That would mean that you are currently using `mysql` extension to connect to MySQL db, which is deprecated.

As a solution, I would recommend [installing mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php).